# Handle logic in react component base on conditional props with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

## Context of my issues

In my form component that will allow me to create or update a user, I want the logic of the latter to be able to distinguish whether the props are defined or not. The purpose is that the form design is the same, just some logic change between create or update.

*The props of my component can be defined by this both interfaces.*

```js
interface ICreateSupportUserModalProps extends IBaseModalProps {
  mode: 'create';
  disabled?: never;
  scopes?: never;
  supportUser?: never;
}

interface IUpdateSupportUserModalProps extends IBaseModalProps {
  mode: 'update';
  disabled?: boolean;
  scopes: string[];
  supportUser: ISupportUser;
}

export type TDashboardUserModalProps = IUpdateSupportUserModalProps | ICreateSupportUserModalProps;
```

After that my component is defined like this

```js
const DashboardUserModalContent: FC<TDashboardUserModalProps> = (props) => {
  ....
}
```

And inside I have some methods that combine logic for both mode.

```js
const onSubmitForm = (dashboardUser: ISupportUserForm) => {
  const errors = handleBeforeSubmit(dashboardUser);

  if (errors) return errors.map((error) => setError(error.name, { message: error.message }));

  const scopes = dashboardUser.role ? getScopesByRole(dashboardUser.role) : [];
  delete dashboardUser.role;

  if (isCreateMode) dispatch(addSupportUser({ ...dashboardUser, scopes }));
  else dispatch(updateSupportUser({ ...dashboardUser, id: props.supportUser.id, scopes }));
};
```

For the moment the only solution have found is to use [typeguard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types).

In the method `onSubmitForm`, I use a typeguard to check the props

```js
const onSubmitForm = (dashboardUser: ISupportUserForm) => {
  ....
  if (isCreateMode) dispatch(addSupportUser({ ...dashboardUser, scopes }));
  else dispatch(updateSupportUser({ ...dashboardUser, id: props.supportUser.id, scopes }));
};
```

**Typeguard :**

```js
function isCreateProps(props: TDashboardUserModalProps): props is ICreateSupportUserModalProps {
  return props.mode === 'create';
}
```

But it's not clean because I can't destructure the props correctly because I need to use the props object to handle my typeguard.

So my expectation is to find a solution to handle my logic without typeguard if possible, and keep one component.

Either there is a solution to be found in typescript so that the component knows which props it receives from its parent or I have to implement a new structure for this component in order to be able to differentiate the props.

Comment: What is the issue when you are accessing the properties? I dont get this *But it's not clean because I can't destructure the props correctly because*